# Is PThreads library still used in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I was wondering is this code from year 2003 still state-of-the-art? It is
the consumer and producer example in C++ using PThreads.

http://www.mario-konrad.ch/wiki/doku.php?id=programming:multithreading:tutorial-06

If not, what is the modern way to work with threads in C++?

Thank you

Comment: Even if not directly, it is as an underlying implementation for something else.

Comment: Since the C++ standard library encapsulates the entire C standard library...

Comment: @H2CO3 pthreads isn't part of either standard library.

Comment: @delnan According to POSIX, it is.

Comment: @H2CO3 POSIX does not define the C standard library. It's a standard alright, but not the C standard.

Comment: @delnan There's a thing called the "POSIX C standard library". Then what the heck is that?

Comment: If you can use C++11, you could use the build in <thread> library.

Comment: POSIX is NOT the C or the C++ standard. It is entirely unrelated. The latest C++ 11 standard has its own <thread> library, as does C11 with its <threads.h>. Both are unrelated to POSIX. POSIX is over a decade older than either standard

Comment: @H2CO3 Google has only 4k mentions of that phrase on the entire internet, and half the first page consists of your stack overflow comments. The term may exist, but it's not terribly common and it's not what most people mean by "standard library". The C standard library (mostly) works even on obscure embedded systems. POSIX is not anywhere as portable.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am interested to learn about the PThreads library. So my question actually was, is this valid in terms of PThreads. The question was not, what is the best way to do threads in C++.

Comment: @delnan [perhaps this is wrong then?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#POSIX_standard_library)

Comment: @delnan And nobody said "POSIX is the C standard". You're twisting my words. No need for that.

Comment: Wikipedia carefully distinguishes between "the C standard library proper" and the additional stuff defined by POSIX. Again, I'm not opposed to the term "POSIX standard library", and feel free to throw in a C, but "standard library" without qualifications *does not* refer to POSIX. Your original comment discussed "the entire C standard library", no mention of POSIX. That's what made me chip in, I don't attempt to twist words.

Comment: @delnan Okay, now I've got your point. What I am saying is there's the ISO (or ANSI? Which one's better to use?) C standard library, and there's the POSIX C standard library which defines additions to the ISO C standard library. And I generally assume POSIX availability because it's portable and convenient.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's perfectly fine and I have no objection to it :-) Though note that most of POSIX is not available on some platforms that are *very* important for many people (most prominently win32), and parts (e.g. fork) can't even be emulated properly. So whether it's portable enough really depends on your needs.

Comment: @delnan That's right, sorry for being nitpicky :) (Well, I wish no one used win32... :/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the pthreads library is still used for threading. There are some higher level libraries (boost, or if you have a c++ 11 compliant compiler, the standard library) that will also give you threading capabilities, although for somethings you will still need to fall back to the plain pthread call. The boost::thread and std::thread libraries use the pthread library for their implementation on operating systems that support pthreads, so even when using those libraries, you are indirectly using pthreads.

So I guess the short answer is yes, the code would still be valid, but now there are other options available too.

Also as a side note, I know Intel has their thread building blocks available, but I haven't used it.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was interested in. I will accept your answer in 6 minutes (there is some time constraint).

Comment: Note that the `push()` and `pop()` functions in http://www.mario-konrad.ch/wiki/doku.php?id=programming:multithreading:tutorial-06 were not state-of-the-art in 2003. In the spin loops where they `usleep()` they should have used pthread condition_variables instead.